# Efficient way to compute cosine similarity between 1D array and all rows in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cosine-similarity

I have one 1D array of shape `(300, )` and a 2D array of shape `(400, 300)`. Now, I want to compute the cosine similarity between each of the rows in this 2D array to the 1D array. Thus, my result should be of shape `(400, )` which represents how similar these vectors are.

My initial idea is to iterate thru the rows in 2D array using a `for` loop and then compute cosine similarity between vectors. Is there a faster alternative using broadcasting method?

Here is a contrived example:

```
In [29]: vec = np.random.randn(300,)
In [30]: arr = np.random.randn(400, 300)
```

Below is the way I want to calculate the similarity between 1D arrays:

```
inn = (vec * arr[0]).sum()  
vecnorm = numpy.sqrt((vec * vec).sum())  
rownorm = numpy.sqrt((arr[0] * arr[0]).sum())  
similarity_score = inn / vecnorm / rownorm
```

How can I generalize this to `arr[0]` being replaced with a 2D array?

Comment: How would your output be (300,)? if you have 400 vectors to "test against" then your output will be (400,), and a simple dot product will do...

Comment: @Julien thanks for spotting the typo. corrected it

Comment: What's your cosine similarity calculation?  You could give us a full working example with arrays like (4,3) and (3,) shapes.

Comment: @hpaulj updated the question with these details. Please check!

Comment: For generalized solution for two 2D arrays see my other post https://stackoverflow.com/a/61643023/13484859

Comment: See this discussion here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55717/efficient-numpy-cosine-distance-calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one following the same method as with [`@Bi Rico's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048673/), but with `einsum` for the `norm` computations -

```
den = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',arr,arr)*np.einsum('j,j',vec,vec))
out = arr.dot(vec) / den
```

Also, we can use `vec.dot(vec)` to replace `np.einsum('j,j',vec,vec)` for some marginal improvement.

Timings -

```
In [45]: vec = np.random.randn(300,)
    ...: arr = np.random.randn(400, 300)

# @Bi Rico's soln with norm
In [46]: %timeit (np.linalg.norm(arr, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(vec))
10000 loops, best of 3: 100 µs per loop

In [47]: %timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',arr,arr)*np.einsum('j,j',vec,vec))
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.4 µs per loop
```

On bigger arrays -

```
In [48]: vec = np.random.randn(3000,)
    ...: arr = np.random.randn(4000, 3000)

In [49]: %timeit (np.linalg.norm(arr, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(vec))
10 loops, best of 3: 22.2 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',arr,arr)*np.einsum('j,j',vec,vec))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.18 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

The numerator of cos similarity can be expressed as a matrix multiply and then the denominator should just work :).

```
a_norm = np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)
b_norm = np.linalg.norm(b)
(a @ b) / (a_norm * b_norm)
```

where `a` is a 2D array and `b` is 1D array (i.e. vector)

Comment: This approach is **10x** faster than the method of using `cdist` from scipy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


x = np.random.rand(1, 300)
Y = np.random.rand(400, 300)

similarities = 1 - cdist(x, Y, metric='cosine')
print(similarities.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(1, 400)
```

Notice that `cdist` returns the `cosine_distance` (more [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html)), that is `1 - cosine_similarity` so you need to convert the result.